# Verifying Webhooks in Podio

Tags: php, api, webhooks, podio

I need to create a webhook in Podio for my application.

**My code is as follows:**

```
// Authenticate the application
\Podio::setup(ID_PODIO, SECRET_PODIO);
\Podio::authenticate('app', array(
    'app_id' => PODIO_ID_ADD,
    'app_token' =>
        PODIO_TOKEN_ADD
));

switch($_POST['type']) {
    case 'hook.verify':
        // Validate the webhook
        \PodioHook::validate($_POST['hook_id'], array(
            'code' =>
                $_POST['code']
        ));
    case 'item.create':
        // Do something. item_id is available in $_POST['item_id']
    case 'item.update':
        // Do something. item_id is available in $_POST['item_id']
    case 'item.delete':
        // Do something. item_id is available in $_POST['item_id']
}
```

Podio does not send the request to my script. My server is not localhost. Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

All details on how to setup Podio webhooks are here: https://developers.podio.com/examples/webhooks

If you are not getting webhook verification call - please check your webhook url and server firewall settings. For debug purposes, I'd recommend:

1. create another webhook
2. use service like https://requestb.in as URL for that webhook
3. click "Verify" button after creating webhook
4. check used service to see if webhook verification request was sent and what's the structure of this request

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified `$_POST['type']`? I would create logging to determine if the incoming request is actually hitting your server, e.g. data validation before just submitting the requests.

```
    if (isset($request['type']) && $request['type'] == 'hook.verify') {
        \PodioHook::validate($request['hook_id'], ['code' => $request['code']]);
        $log->message = "Podio hook validation";
        $log->status = "Complete";
        $log->request = json_encode($request);
        $log->save();
        return;
    }
```

1) are you validating that the request is or is not hitting your server?

2) are you actually successfully requesting hook validation, and if so, how?

3) is your authentication actually working?

2 breaks for me the most.. I'll regularly find that hook validation won't work when building that portion from scratch.